# Replace nan values with the value of the closest date in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My current problem goes as follows. Consider the dataframe:

```
       name     score   date
0      Alice    22.0    2020-12-31
15     Alice    4.0     2005-12-31
5      Alice    1.0     2003-12-31
10     Alice    NaN     2000-12-31
6      Bob      8.0     2001-11-02
16     Bob      1.0     2004-11-02
11     Bob      5.0     2003-11-02
1      Bob      45.0    1980-11-02
12     Chuck    9.0     2003-12-03
2      Chuck    4.0     2015-12-03
7      Chuck    9.0     2001-12-03
17     Chuck    2.0     2004-12-03
18     Daren    3.0     2004-03-13
21     Daren    89.0    2015-08-13
3      Daren    NaN     2015-03-13
20     Daren    12.0    2015-05-13
8      Daren    5.0     2015-03-17
13     Daren    93.0    2003-03-13
14     Elisa    11.0    2003-01-24
9      Elisa    19.0    2001-01-24
19     Elisa    23.0    2004-01-24
4      Elisa    16.0    2010-01-24
```

Some `score` values are `nan`. I would like to replace these values with the person's closest score (w.r.t. `time`), GIVEN that the time difference is within 1 year, i.e. 365 days. If there is no such time, then keep the value as `nan`.

In the dataframe above, Daren's `nan` score value would be replaced to 5, as there is a score which was recorded within a year of the `nan` date and it is the smallest time difference from the other possible scores. However for Alice, there is no such score which was recorded within a year of the `nan` score, thus her `nan` score will be kept as `nan`.

To reproduce the dataframe, use this code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {"name": ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Chuck', 'Daren', 'Elisa', 'Alice', 'Bob', 'Chuck', 'Daren', 'Elisa','Alice', 'Bob', 'Chuck', 'Daren', 'Elisa','Alice', 'Bob', 'Chuck', 'Daren', 'Elisa','Daren','Daren'],
        "score": [22,45,4,np.nan,16,1,8,9,5,19,np.nan,5,9,93,11,4,1,2,3,23,12,89],
        "date": ['31/12/2020','11/02/1980','12/03/2015','13/03/2015','24/01/2010','31/12/2003','11/02/2001','12/03/2001','17/03/2015','24/01/2001','31/12/2000','11/02/2003','12/03/2003','13/03/2003','24/01/2003','31/12/2005','11/02/2004','12/03/2004','13/03/2004','24/01/2004','13/05/2015','13/08/2015']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.sort_values(by='name')
```

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to read the df if you sorted by name and date. You could probably get rid of the irrelevant names too, for the sake of example, or at least some of them.

Comment: It'd help to provide a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341). I had to do a bit of work to get this into a usable state: `pd.read_csv(..., sep=' ', skipinitialspace=True, dtype={'score': 'Int64'}, parse_dates=['date'], dayfirst=True)`

Comment: Yes @wjandrea it's hard when trying to reproduce table while testing..messing arround with dates and names from past 20 minutes

Comment: Noted. Please see the code attached. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming df is the same dataframe as given in the question above:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y') # Create a datetime out of date column
df = df.sort_values('date').reset_index(drop=True) # Sorting the dates to get closest values from NaN
nan_index = df.index[df['score'].isna()].to_list() # Get all index values where value is NaN
for idx in nan_index: # Loop over all NaN values and check condition
    if idx-1 < 0: # If no time available previously, we skip such cases as there is no score within a year.
        continue
    curr_date = df.at[idx, 'date']
    prev_date = df.at[idx-1, 'date']
    if ((curr_date - prev_date).days <= 365): # Check if time difference is within 365 days
        df.at[idx, 'score'] = df.at[idx+1, 'score'] # Replace NaN with next closest value
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

First sort values based on `names` and extract year from date column. Then group by `year`

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(['name'])
df = df.sort_values(['date'])
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year
print(df.groupby('year').bfill())
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Gives #

```
     name  score       date
0   Alice   22.0 2020-12-31
1     Bob   45.0 1980-11-02
2   Chuck    4.0 2015-12-03
3   Daren    5.0 2015-03-13
4   Elisa   16.0 2010-01-24
5   Alice    1.0 2003-12-31
6     Bob    8.0 2001-11-02
7   Chuck    9.0 2001-12-03
8   Daren    5.0 2015-03-17
9   Elisa   19.0 2001-01-24
10  Alice    NaN 2000-12-31
11    Bob    5.0 2003-11-02
12  Chuck    9.0 2003-12-03
13  Daren   93.0 2003-03-13
14  Elisa   11.0 2003-01-24
15  Alice    4.0 2005-12-31
16    Bob    1.0 2004-11-02
17  Chuck    2.0 2004-12-03
18  Daren    3.0 2004-03-13
19  Elisa   23.0 2004-01-24
20  Daren   12.0 2015-05-13
21  Daren   89.0 2015-08-13
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. However, doesn't this just look at the nearest date within the year? Rather than looking for the nearest date _within_ +/- 365 days.

Comment: Ahh I just seen if output matches above case...If you want for +/- days group by entire date

Comment: Would you be able to modify the code above? Sorry I still don't understand

Comment: I guess we are sorting date first and & then extracting year in my code...It should satisify  looking for the nearest date within +/- 365 days. Logic I've given perfectly fits your case mentioned above

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would you be able to modify the code so that myself and others viewing the thread could see?

Comment: Have you tried above code? Deos it have any issue...I guess no need to edit anything..Logic should work above mentioned case

Comment: Worked? deos require any modifications?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = df.sort_values(by=['name', 'date'])

data = pd.concat([data,
           data.shift(-1)[['score', 'date']].rename(columns={'score': 'score_next', 'date': 'date_next'}),
           data.shift(1)[['score', 'date']].rename(columns={'score': 'score_prev', 'date': 'date_prev'})
           ],
          axis=1)

def setter(x):
    r = x['date'] - x['date_prev']
    r = float('inf') if type(r) == pd._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType else abs(r.days)
    v = x['date'] - x['date_prev']
    v = float('inf') if type(v) == pd._libs.tslibs.nattype.NaTType else abs(v.days)
    if r > v:
        return x['score_prev']
    return x['score_next']
    
df.score.fillna(data[data.score.isna()].apply(setter, axis=1), inplace=True)
```